# Python - Request Module - Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, networking, python-requests

I am running into an issue where I am getting a generic remote end closed connection error:

```
Remote end closed connection without response
```

when using Python 3.5 and the requests module.

Here is an example of the code - but i'm not using any kwargs at the moment:

```
response = self._requests_session.get(self._nextUri, **self._requests_kwargs)
```

Here is the full error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1213, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1213, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

I am wondering what sort of additional code I add to get more information about this error or to make the connection more resilient.

I have tried taking a TCPDump capture of this issue but i'm not having anything stick out after reviewing, I am looking for some high level detail that I can get from Python or some additional things I can do to make the session more resilient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an issue with EKS and Kubernetes.

The issue was that there seemed to be a port collision with SNAT which caused these unexpected connection errors.

It's well documented [here](https://tech.xing.com/a-reason-for-unexplained-connection-timeouts-on-kubernetes-docker-abd041cf7e02) and [here](https://engineering.prezi.com/https-engineering-prezi-com-a-kubernetes-crime-story-2e8d75a77630):

The solution was to upgrade to Kubernetes 1.15 and adding the CNI var below:
`AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_RANDOMIZESNAT=prng`